# Can this be acomplished using only CSS? (no JS)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

One container with a text background, where the container can grow to fit the size of the biggest of either the content or the text background.

The closest I've got is using a flexbox container with two inner DIVs, one for the content and one for the text background. Both with flex-basis of 100%, and the background with -100% margin on one side so the content can overlap it.

The problem with this layout is that it's not so obvious where the padding in the background text is coming from. I would expect the blue and red dashed lines to touch each other, but there is the padding.

```css
.test1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.test2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 50px;
}

.test3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 250px;
}

.test4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 250px;
}

.test5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 450px;
}

.test6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 450px;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  outline: dashed 3px green;
  padding: 3px;
}

.title {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.foreground {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  outline: dashed 3px blue;
}

.left {
  background: rgba(255,255,0,.5);
}

.right {
  background: rgba(0,255,255,.5);
  text-align: right;
}

.background {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  margin-right: -100%;

  font-size: 30px;
  outline: dashed 3px red;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background>div {
  outline: dashed 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer test1">
  <div class="background">
     <div>1 some very long text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
    <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test2">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>2 text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test3">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>3 some very long text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test4">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>4 text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test5">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>5 some very long text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCDxxxxx</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test6">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>6 text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCDxxxxx</div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

This would be the expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would you want to have the red container fit its parent and increase in size accordingly, only `flex: 1;` is needed for this div and optionally `text-align: center;` for centering the text.

```css
.test1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.test2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 50px;
}

.test3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 250px;
}

.test4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 250px;
}

.test5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 450px;
}

.test6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 450px;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.title {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.foreground {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  outline: dashed 3px blue;
}

.left {
  background: rgba(255,255,0,.5);
}

.right {
  background: rgba(0,255,255,.5);
  text-align: right;
}

.background {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  margin-right: -100%;

  font-size: 30px;
  outline: dashed 3px red;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background>div {
  outline: dashed 3px red;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer test1">
  <div class="background">
     <div>1 some very long text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
    <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test2">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>2 text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test3">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>3 some very long text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test4">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>4 text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test5">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>5 some very long text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCDxxxxx</div>
 </div>
  
    <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer test6">  
  <div class="background">
 <div>6 text!!!</div>
  </div>

  <div class="foreground">
 <div class="left">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
   <div>ABC</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCD</div>
   <div>ABCDxxxxx</div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="right">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>AB</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would expect the blue one to shrink since there is a lot of room between the yellow and cyan containers. I added a screen capture with the expected result. Thanks.